# Convert timestamp gives result in the future

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have this timestamp "1500473911936" and I'm trying to do

```
select DATE_TRUNC('second',to_timestamp(1500473911936))
```

and it gives "49518-02-16 04:52:16+00" instead of "2017-07-19 14:24:00+01" as I do with

```
select DATE_TRUNC('second',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds,
and you are expecting seconds

Try dividing by 1000

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is in millisecond format. Did you try 'millisecond' instead of 'second'?

select DATE_TRUNC('millisecond',to_timestamp(1500473911936))